# Overloaded operator not throwing exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, operator-overloading

I have a class that contains a map

```
Any& Map::operator[]( const unsigned int field ) const
{
  try
  {
    iterator it;
    if ((it = m_fields.find(field)) != m_fields.end())
      return it->second;

    throw std::runtime_error("Field " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(field) + " not found.");
  }
  catch(boost::bad_any_cast& )
  {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed conversion field " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(field)  + " using boost::any_cast ");
  }
}
```

I want it to throw an exception when the field does not exists in the map so the program does not crash on a bad get, but the throw does not seem to work on the overloaded operator, the program crashes anyway so either the throw or the catch are being ignored. If I use the same code but with a common function

```
Any& Map::get( const unsigned int field ) const
{
  //...
```

it works.

Did I ran in some c++ limitation or am I doing something wrong?

**--EDIT :**

I ran the debugger and to my surprise that code doesn't even execute, another method does

```
Any& Map::operator[]( const unsigned int  field )
{
  iterator it;
  if ((it = m_fields.find(field)) == m_fields.end())
  {
    Any newValue;
    m_fields[field] = newValue;
    return m_fields[field];
  }

  return it->second;
}
```

and the crash occurs because of a boost assert on Any that tries to convert a uninitialized variable. This method is probably used on inserts on the map, like

```
Map a;
a[3] = "foo";
```

So I guess I have no way to differentiate when the operator is used on an atribution or on a get and the use of this operator is highly unsafe for gets

Comment: The code you posted looks correct, so something else is going wrong. single-step it in a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: Personally I would put the `find` and the comparison on different lines

Comment: It's (probably) not the cause of your problem, but you'll need to return by value - you can't return a reference to a temporary.

Comment: @pkit And initialize `it` in the statement which defined it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Where do you see the return of a temporary?  The only return I see is `return it->second`, and that returns a reference to an element in the map (which isn't a temporary).

Comment: @JamesKanze: I guess I was assuming that there was a conversion involved (hence the need to catch `bad_any_cast`). If the map does contain `Any`, then the code is probably fine.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'll admit that the `bad_any_cast` confused me as well.  But I think `bad_any_cast` is only thrown when converting _from_ an any.  And if there were an implicit conversion in the `return` the code shouldn't compile, since that would entail initializing a non-const reference with a temporary.  (Of course, if he's using the Microsoft compiler...)

Answer (score 2):

Re your edit: overload resolution generally only takes into account the
arguments, not the use.  If you have a const and a non-const function
with otherwise identical signatures, the non-const will be chosen if
possible (e.g. called on a non-const object).

In a case where you do want different behavior depending on the use, the
traditional solution is to provide a proxy.  Your `Map` class would
contain two functions `get` and `set`, and the non-const `operator[]` would return a
proxy which looks something like:

```
class Proxy  // member of Map
{
    Map* myOwner;
    int myIndex;
public:
    Proxy( Map* owner, int index )
        : myOwner( owner )
        , myIndex( index )
    {
    }
    void operator=( Any const& rhs ) const
    {
        myOwner->put( myIndex, rhs );
    }
    operator Any() const
    {
        return myOwner->get( myIndex );
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 for the proxy. The `Proxy` "pattern" is often disregarded even though it's probably one of the most volatile patterns I have seen.